# How exactly does a variadic parameter work?

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

I'm a Swift newbie and am having a bit of trouble understanding what a variadic parameter is exactly, and why it's useful. I'm currently following along with the online Swift 5.3 guide, and this is the example that was given for this type of parameter.

```
func arithmeticMean(_ numbers: Double...) -> Double {
    var total: Double = 0
    for number in numbers {
        total += number
    }
    return total / Double(numbers.count)
}
arithmeticMean(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
// returns 3.0, which is the arithmetic mean of these five numbers
arithmeticMean(3, 8.25, 18.75)
// returns 10.0, which is the arithmetic mean of these three numbers
```

Apparently, the variadic parameter called `numbers` has a type of `Double...`, which allows it to be used in the body of the function as a constant array. Why does the function return `Double(numbers.count)` instead of just `numbers.count`? And instead of creating a variadic parameter, why not just create a parameter that takes in an array that's outside of the function like this?

```
func addition(numbers : [Int]) -> Int
{
    var total : Int = 0
    for number in numbers
    {
        total += number
    }
    return total
}

let totalBruhs : [Int] = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 69]
addition(numbers: totalBruhs)
```

Also, why can there only be one variadic parameter per function?

Comment: “Why does the function return `Double(numbers.count)` instead of just `numbers.count`?” ... It’s not. It’s returning the sum of the values (which is a double) divided by how many numbers there are. But `number.count` is a integer, and you can’t divide a `Double` by an integer. So you have to convert the integer count to a double before using it in the division operation. That’s the point of the `Double(numbers.count)` in that `return` expression.

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn’t use variadic parameter for calculating the mean of a sequence of numbers. Then again, I wouldn’t do it on array of `Double`, either. I’d might do it on `Sequence` and use `FloatingPoint` protocol. For example, https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/92edae4b0ca41455ad26253770a7fc5c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic parameters need (well, not *need*, but nice) to exist in Swift because they exist in C, and many things in Swift bridge to C. In C, creating a quick array of arbitrary length is not so simple as in Swift.

If you were building Swift from scratch with no backwards compatibility to C, then maybe they'd have been added, and maybe not. (Though I'm betting yes, just because so many Swift developers are used to languages where they exist. But then again, languages like Zig have intentionally gotten rid of variadic parameters, so I don't know. Zig also demonstrates that you don't *need* variadic parameters to bridge to C, but still, it's kind of nice. *And @Rob's comments below are worth reading. He's probably not wrong. Also, [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63321819/97337) is insightful.*)

But they're also convenient because you don't need to add the `[...]`, which makes it much nicer when there's just one value. In particular, consider something like `print`:

```
func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n")
```

Without variadic parameters, you'd need to put `[...]` in every `print` call, or you'd need overloads. Variadic doesn't change the world here, but it's kind of nice. It's particularly nice when you think about the ambiguities an overload would create. Say you didn't have variadics and instead had two overloads:

```
func print(_ items: [Any]) { ... }
func print(_ item: Any) { print([item]) }
```

That's actually a bit ambiguous, since Array is also a kind of Any. So `print([1,2,3])` would print `[[1,2,3]]`. I'm sure there's some possible work-arounds, but variadics fix that up very nicely.

There can be only one because otherwise there are ambiguous cases.

```
func f(_ xs: Int..., _ ys: Int...)
```

What should `f(1,2,3)` do in this case? What is `xs` and what is `ys`?

The function you've shown here doesn't return `Double(numbers.count)`. It converts `numbers.count` to a Double so it can be divided into another Double. The function returns `total / Double(numbers.count)`.

Comment: @Rob_Napier Ah, so these parameters exist in part because of the relationship between Swift and C, and also to make the program a bit simpler. I assume from your answer then that variadic parameters aren't all that important then?

Comment: I’m not sure if I’d drag C interoperability into this question, especially since interop of variadic functions between the languages is not what one would have hoped for. (See [Using Imported C Functions in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift).) I can understand Zig’s design choices, but I think there are lots of cases where variadic pattern is the logical pattern and Swift’s native support for them seems quite reasonable. I don’t think we need to appeal to C interoperability for motivation.

Comment: @Rob You make a good counter-argument there. Updated the answer to point people to it.

Answer (score 1):

> And instead of creating a variadic parameter, why not just create a parameter that takes in an array that's outside of the function ... ?

I agree with you that it feels intuitive to use arrays for arithmetic functions like “mean”, “sum”, etc.

That having been said, there are situations where the variadic pattern feels quite natural:

1. There are scenarios where you are writing a function where using an array might not be logical or intuitive at the calling point.

   Consider a `max` function that is supposed to be returning the larger of two values. It doesn’t feel quite right to impose a constraint that the caller *must* create an array of these values in order to return the larger of two values. You really want to allow a nice, simple syntax:

   ```
    let result = max(a, b)
   ```

   But at the same time, as an API developer, there’s also no reason to restrict the `max` implementation to only allow two parameters. Maybe the caller might want to use three. Or more. As an API developer, we design API’s for naturally calling points for the primary use cases, but provide as much flexibility as we can. So a variadic function parameter is both very natural and very flexible.

   There are lots of possible example of this pattern, namely any function that naturally feels like it should take two parameters, but might take more. Consider a `union` function for two rectangles and you want the bounding rectangle. Again, you don’t want the caller to have to create an array for what might be a simple union of two rectangles.
2. Another common example would be where you might have a variable number of parameters but might not be dealing with arrays. The classic example would be `printf` pattern. Or another is where you are interacting with some SQL database and might be binding values to `?` placeholders in the SQL or the like (to protect against SQL injection attacks):

   ```
    let sql = "SELECT book_id, isbn FROM books WHERE title = ? AND author = ?"
    let resultSet = db.query(sql, title, author)
   ```

   Again, in these cases, suggesting that the caller must create an array for this heterogenous collection of values might not feel natural at the calling point.

So, the question isn’t “why would I use variadic parameter where arrays are logical and intuitive?” but rather “why would I force the use of array parameters where it might not be?”